# Ratio between origin and error

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a formula called: Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio

`SNR = 10 * log10 * (P_orig * P_err )`

For this formula i have one example, it is about an image `_orig` with the pixel grey values **[4, 8, 4, 6, 3]**

When this image is transformed to a jpeg compression it has the `_err` pixel values of **[-1, 1, 0, -2, 1]**

The  **SNR**  formula for this values is:

`SNR = 10 * log10 * ((141/5) * (7/5))`

**My problem** is that i don't understand how `P_orig` and `P_err` are calculated.
 **In my example** i can see that `P_` stands for `power`

and i **think** that `141` divided through `5` because the image has 5 values [4,8,4,6,3] but how does the autor:

**come from [4,8,4,6,3] to 141**

**and form [-1,1,0,-2,1] to  7**

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be the sums of the squares of the listed elements:

$$4^2+8^2+4^2+6^2+3^2=141$$

$$(-1)^2+1^1+0^2+(-2)^2+1^2=7$$